# Open a window with another window?

Tags: java, vaadin

I have a window in my vaadin project and now I want to open another window over that.

I'm trying this.

```
public class MyWindow extends Window {
    /** this is a window that I want open */ 
    public MyWindow() {
        super("MyWindow");
        center();
        VerticalLayout vLayout = new VerticalLayout();
        vLayout.addComponent(new Label("MyWindow is opened");
        setContent(vLayout);
    }
}

public class OpenMyWindow extends Window {
    /** this is a window that should open MyWindow */
    private Button btnOpenMyWindow;
    public OpenMyWindow() {
        super("OpenMyWindow");
        center();
        VerticalLayout vLayout = new VerticalLayout();
        btnOpenMyWindow = new Button("Open My Window");
        btnOpenMyWindow.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {   
            @Override       
            public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                new MyWindow().setVisible(true);
            }     
        });
        vLayout.addComponent(btnOpenMyWindow);
        setContent(vLayout);
    } 
}
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [UI.addWindow](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/UI.html#addWindow%28com.vaadin.ui.Window%29) method:

```
...
MyWindow myWindow = new MyWindow();
UI.getCurrent().addWindow(myWindow);
...
```

Please, check out [Vaadin Book chapter on subwindows.](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/layout.sub-window.html)